# Why is unix.stackexchange.com not using dark mode?

Tags: discussion, meta, stackexchange

StackExchange has had an option for a while now that allows users to use the dark mode theme on the website. I've noticed that all the stack exchange sites I use, are in dark mode, yet this one is not... Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: Dark mode is only enabled for Stack Overflow and its translations into other languages. Looking at your profile, none of the sites you use have it except SO, if you see them in dark mode, then you have some user script or style doing it.

Comment: @terdon oops, yeah I forgot about Darkreader. My bad.